# Backtick (MySQL norm) added to SQL Server Query causing error

Tags: sql

We are using Wordpress as an internal Wiki.

We are using SQL Server. I know Wordpress is geared towards MySQL.

An article will not post if there is a backslash in the article. It will just save the article as "auto-draft" but it will then clear your submission page and all your work will be done .

You can use a forward slash, but when a backslash is entered, all is lost.

I know it is not the (Frontier) plugin - it happens on the normal post in admin - which does not use any plugin.

I used SQL Server Profiler. When there is a backslash, the SQL parameters incorrectly get enclosed by a

> `

(grave accent / backtick) character. This is what is causing the problem.
[image]

I’ve also just found this:
After the first column that had the forward slash, all columns following thereafter in the SQL statement, erroneously get the backticks

How do I get rid of the backtick?

I have installed updated drivers for PHP_SQL_Server : 4.0.

I updated the drivers in php.ini :
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv.dll

and wp-config.php
/** Database Type. Defaults to mysql */
define('DB_TYPE', 'pdo_sqlsrv');

But after these updates, the site does not work at all.

```
WordPress database error 42000 : [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '`'. for query UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = yyy, post_date =  N'2017-04-16 16:52:44.000', post_date_gmt =  N'2017-04-16 14:52:44.000', post_content =  N'\\ \', `post_content_filtered` =  N'', `post_title` =  N'test \\', `post_excerpt` =  N'', `post_status` =  N'draft', `post_type` =  N'post', `comment_status` =  N'closed', `ping_status` =  N'open', `post_password` =  N'', WHERE ID = xxx made by edit_post, wp_update_post, wp_insert_post, pdo_wpdb->query, pdo_wpdb->_post_query, pdo_wpdb->print_error
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't simulate this on a clean install of WordPress. So probably there is some extra filtering of XSS/Injection prevention happening on the server side. You should probably check that out first.

[image]

Comment: Hi Niels, when I create a post, and the post has a backslash, then the SQL that I am seeing, gets the backtick as indicated (It seems the example you posted has a backtick in the text - not around the SQL)

Comment: @PeterPitLock no difference there on a clean install. Backslashes are working to. So my answer stands, it's something different then WordPress. Probably an pro-active SQL injection filter on the server.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server did you use? Did you use any plugins like frontier? Wondering if this could be frontier

Comment: @PeterPitLock MySQL 5.6 on a clean install (no plugins). I do this to eliminate the possibility that its a WordPress bug. Enable all your plugins to see if it persists. If not, enable them one by one to find the culprit.

Comment: The problem is this is SQL Server and not MySQL. It is definitely a major part of the problem. I did disable all the plugins - except I could not disable Frontier - and it still persisted.